# Error Compiling Scala Spark using SBT Console in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I tried to compile Scala Spark project that I got using get-idea following this tutorial https://anitatailor.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/setting-up-spark0-8-0-with-intellijidea/

But when I tried to compile Scala Spark using SBT Console in IntelliJ IDEA, I got some errors.
You may see the error logs below

```
java -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar C:\Users\Priska\.IdeaIC14\system\sbt\sbt-launch.jar 

[info] Loading project definition from D:\spark-incubating\project\project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to D:\spark-incubating\project\project\target\scala-2.9.2\sbt-0.12\classes...
[error] error while loading CharSequence, class file 'D:\IDEA\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1501)
[error] error while loading Comparator, class file 'D:\IDEA\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Comparator.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 5003)
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Often when you open some project that compiles perfectly from command line in Intellij Idea it doesn't. I personally have issues with running scala console with spark - starts to compile whole project and fails...